# Linear Algebra Proof using nonsingularity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

In my Linear Algebra course I have come across multiple questions of the sort which I cannot seem to answer.

Let $A\in  \mathbb R^{n×n}$ , $B\in  \mathbb R^{n×m}$, and $C\in  \mathbb R^{m×n}$.

If $A$ and $I − CA^{-1}B$ are nonsingular, show that $A − BC$ is nonsingular and

$(A − BC)^{-1} = A^{-1} + A^{-1}B(I − CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}$.

Edit: Any places where I can find rules and tricks on solving these kinds of matrix equations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you give us some insight on how you came across this question and what you tried to do to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried multiply $A - BC$ and $A^{-1} + A^{-1}B(I - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by multiplying $A-BC$ and $A^{-1} + A^{-1}B(I - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}$ you get the desired result, I strongly suggest you to try it yourself before looking at the following.

> \begin{align*}
> &(A-BC)(A^{-1} + A^{-1}B(I - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1})\\
> =&I-BCA^{-1}+B(I - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}-BCA^{-1}B(I - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}\\
> =&I-BCA^{-1}+B(I-CA^{-1}B)(I - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}\\
> =&I-BCA^{-1}+BCA^{-1}\\
> =&I
> \end{align*}

Comment: Oooh I did not think of that, thank you very much. I did try it before looking at what you wrote under and successfully proved it thanks again. Could you maybe give me a hint on the first part, proving non-singularity in A-BC from I-CA^(-1)B?

Comment: The existence of inverse is enough for proving the non singularity. You use the non singularity of the two matrix you mention by taking their inverse.

Comment: Yes, but from what I understood the question consist of two parts and I imagine you cannot use what is given in the second part to prove the first part. As in, the second part uses the inverse of A-BC but I do not think it is sufficient to answer A-BC is nonsingular because the inverse is used in the equation thereafter.

Comment: my point is simply that this answer uses the nonsingularity of $A-BC$ by when we take the inverse. Proving the second point proves the first one. I do not know how to prove the second one alone without using that.